# Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4'

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting this error while debugging my code in visual studio 2015:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Unexpected error -
>   Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android
>   profile?  DTR_ACMS

I tried to reinstall Android Support Library v4.

My code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using TaskStackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder;

namespace DTR_ACMS
{
    [Activity(Label = "DTR_ACMS", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        private static readonly int ButtonClickNotificationId = 1000;
        private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Set up an intent so that tapping the notifications returns to this app:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            // Create a PendingIntent; we're only using one PendingIntent (ID = 0):
            const int pendingIntentId = 0;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            // Build the notification:
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)                    // Dismiss from the notif. area when clicked
                .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked")      // Set its title
                .SetNumber(count)                       // Display the count in the Content Info
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click)  // Display this icon
                .SetContentText(String.Format(
                    "The button has been clicked {0} times.", count)); // The message to display.

            // Finally, publish the notification:
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());

            // Increment the button press count:
            count++;
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also got the similar issue, if a single file was open , Visual studio gives such error. By closing that file and restarting Visual studio it solve my problem.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67182/monodroid-error-xa0000-with-unexpected-error-with-reason-system-io-filenotfoundexception